# How to loop through Registry with cmd

Tags: loops, variables, batch-file, registry

I would like to

1. Loop for a registry path - lets say `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Mozilla\Firefox`, which has several sub-paths (in my case databases like DB1, DB2, DB3) like Firefox, Mozilla Firefox, Developer Edition and so on
2. Take each of this sub-paths and put a (always the same) key into it

Unfortunately I have problems using for /f ... %%a (cmd says always %%a was unexpected at this time).

I would have a string (like `reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Firefox\DB1\\|findstr /I  "DB"|findstr /V "Test"`), but using this "command" within the for /f ... ('') command says that I may not use | pipes.

So I would need to handle with the sub-path (DB1, DB2, Mozilla, Mozilla Firefox.
Additionally please help me in finding a way greping out the key-name after `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Firefox\` - so that I would have a variable filled with "DB1".

If I would have this values, I would add astatic value like "reg add `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Mozilla\Firefox\Extensions /t REG_DWORD /d 0x15F90 /f`.

Soleni

Comment: Hard to read your code, don't you think?? Please reformat your question! Use the Code Sample `{}` button or *Ctrl+K*! Then read at least the [tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)! If you are using pipes within the command line parsed by `for /F`, you need to escape it like `^|`...

Answer (score 2):

**Try the following batch file (RegLoopValue.cmd):**

```
@echo off 
setlocal
for /f "tokens=*" %%k in ('reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Mozilla\Firefox') do (
  echo reg add %%k\Extensions /t REG_DWORD /d 0x15F90 /f
  )
endlocal
```

Notes:

- Remove the `echo` before `reg add` when you are happy with the batch file.

**Example output (on my system):**

```
> RegLoopValue.cmd
reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Mozilla\Firefox\Extensions\Extensions /t REG_DWORD /d 0x15F90 /f
reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Mozilla\Firefox\TaskBarIDs\Extensions /t REG_DWORD /d 0x15F90 /f
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [reg](http://ss64.com/nt/reg.html) - Read, Set or Delete registry keys and values, save and restore from a .REG file.

Comment: finally I did it this way:
<code>
{@echo on
for /F %%i in ('dir %1 /b /o:gn  ^| findstr DB_NAME*%2*') do echo reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\%SOFTWARENAME%\%%i\%%i\CLIENT\SWITCHES /v %KEYNAME_TO_ADD% /t REG_SZ -d "%VALUE%" /f
for /F %%i in ('dir %1 /b /o:gn  ^| findstr DB_NAME*%2*') do reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\%SOFTWARENAME%\%%i\%%i\CLIENT\SWITCHES /v %KEYNAME_TO_ADD% /t REG_SZ -d "%VALUE%" /f
pause}
</code>
I don´t get it with the code-block, sorry... :)
thx everybody for your help!